# Forbidden Error When typing fast in input field

Tags: reactjs, github-api, http-status-code-403

I am getting a **forbidden error** 403 in Browser **when I type too fast** in the input field. I am using **React Js with Node and Express** on the Backend.

Following is my code that hold the input.

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';   

export default class SearchBox extends Component {

   constructor(props) {    
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: "", 
            typing :false,
            typingTimeOut :0,
        };
        this.changeName=this.changeName.bind(this);
        this.sendtoParent=this.sendtoParent.bind(this);
    }

    changeName(event) {
        const self=this;

        if(self.state.typingTimeOut)
        {
            clearTimeout(typingTimeOut);
        }

        self.setState({ 
            name: event.target.value,
            typing:false,
            typing: setTimeout(function(){ 
                self.sendtoParent(self.state.name)},1000)
        }); 
    }

    sendtoParent(){    
        this.props.searching(this.state.name,"true");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div >
                 <input 
                    style={styles}
                    id="SearchBox"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder='Enter the name'
                    onChange={this.changeName} 
                 />                  
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

My name goes to the Parent which later gives me the required json from **Github Search API.** My code is working perfectly when i type normally but It gives the 403 error on Typing Fast.

Comment: whats the use of `typing:false` ? do you want to block typing during the api call ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github has a limit on the number of requests per second you can send. You are trying to introduce a timeout in your method to delay the sending of requests, which is a nice approach, but the way it is implemented it's not going to work.

The easiest way is to modify your changeName function to something like this:

```
changeName(event) {
    const self=this;

    if(self.typingTimeOut)
    {
        clearTimeout(self.typingTimeOut);
    }

    self.typingTimeOut = setTimeout(function(){ 
            self.sendtoParent(self.state.name)},1000);

    self.setState({ 
        name: event.target.value,
        typing:false
    }); 
}
```

Comment: It partially worked. In some cases I am still getting the error. To remove the error and start again I need to restart my server. Is there some way by which i can rollback to the state before the error occured? Because once the Forbidden error is comming.. it continues to come even for correct values or when i type slowly.

Comment: It looks like you are getting close to your api limit. Check this site: https://developer.github.com/v3/rate_limit/ and adapt the script to something you are certain wouldn't break that limit. i.e. increasing the timeout